# How to make sure one function executes after the completion of another function in Python?

Tags: python, post, promise, bottle, concurrent.futures

I have two functions - one is processing images that are saved to a folder and another is deleting the image to make room for new images. These functions are triggered through an HTTP POST request, from which image information is also extracted.

In my current implementation, I'm calling the delete function after the process function, but it appears that sometimes the delete will happen before and there is no image to process.

Besides futures, is there another way in Python to ensure that a function only executes after the first function is complete? Something like the promises in Ruby or Javascript

```
from bottle import route, run, request
from process import process, delete

@route('/camera', method='POST')
def index():

    imageId = request.forms.get('imageId')
    process(imageId)
    delete(imageId)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: does the process function return anything?

Comment: How about move `delete(imageId)` inside `process(imageId)`? you can check `if imageId is None` and *file existence* in 1 place.

Comment: What exactly does `process` do? In particular, are you sure it closes the file? Also: if `process` fails, does it do so silently (without creating a file)?

Comment: @Garrett Process function doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Gang I originally had the delete inside process, but took it out to see if I could better control when the delete happens

Comment: @ Ron actually it's more spotty. Sometimes process works and other times we receive an openCV error associated with attempt at processing an image that isn't there.